How can I run a batch file with command line arguments using AutoIT
webui.bat --use-zluda --debug --autolaunch

I want to run this batch file (webui.bat) with these command line arguments (--use-zluda --debug --autolaunch).
The batch file is located at 'F:\automatic\webui.bat'.
Run as Administrator is not mandatory.
Tried:
$cmdPath = Chr(34) &"F:\automatic\webui.bat" &Chr(34)
Run(@ComSpec & " /c " & $cmdPath, "")

Which is returning with -

"C:\Program Files (x86)\AutoIt3\SciTE..\Aut2Exe\Aut2exe.exe" /in "F:\run.au3"
Exit code: 0

Also how can I run it with the command line arguments?

I'm not familiar with AutoIT, but based on the lack of mention of arguments in the documentation, it looks like you just include them as part of $cmdPath, like $cmdPath = Chr(34) &"F:\automatic\webui.bat  --use-zluda --debug --autolaunch" &Chr(34) (again, I have no idea if you've written the syntax correctly)

It looks like the AutoIT code causes calling the Windows kernel library function CreateProcess with %ComSpec% /c "F:\automatic\webui.bat" with an empty string for the current working directory which means using the current working directory of AutoIT process and with the environment variable reference %ComSpec% already expanded by AutoIT to C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe. The double quotes at beginning and end of the batch file name specified with Chr(34) are not needed at all.

34 is the hexadecimal code point value of the character ". F:\automatic\webui.bat does not contain a space or one of these characters &()[]{}^=;!'+,`~. Surrounding " are not needed in this case although they can be nevertheless used here. Run in a command prompt window cmd /? to get output the help of the Windows Command Processor which explains the options like /C and how the command line specified with one or more argument strings after /C or /K is interpreted by cmd.exe depending on various criteria. The execution was successful as returned is exit code 0 by cmd.

However, it looks like really needed is just the single line Run(@ComSpec & " /D /C F:\automatic\webui.bat --use-zluda --debug --autolaunch", "F:\automatic") which results in execution of %ComSpec% /D /C F:\automatic\webui.bat --use-zluda --debug --autolaunch with F:\automatic set as current working directory for cmd.exe by CreateProcess in case of the batch file expects that the directory containing the batch file is also the current working directory of cmd.exe processing the batch file.

AutoIt's Run will simply pass everything to @ComSpec. There is also no need to extra quote the execution string. Your code should simply be:
$cmdPath = "F:\automatic\webui.bat --use-zluda --debug --autolaunch"
Run(@ComSpec & " /c " & $cmdPath, "")

